# Emacs minibuffer completion

Tags: emacs, elisp, launcher, tab-completion, minibuffer

I have a function that launches programs asynchronously:

```lisp
(defun app (app-name)
  (interactive "sRun application: ")
  (async-shell-command app-name))
```

And i have a list of all executables from which to choose. I want the `app` function to behave as `switch-to-buffer`, providing TAB-completion for user. How do i use minibuffer completion in Emacs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `completing-read` command. The function will look like

```lisp
(defun app ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((app-name (completing-read "Run application: " program-list)))
    (async-shell-command app-name)))
```

---

Possibly more idiomatic is to use `interactive` instead of assigning to a variable according to [Emacs Lisp Idioms: Prompting for User Input](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_idioms_prompting_input.html):

```
(defun app (app-name)
  (interactive (list (completing-read "Run application: " app-list)))
  (async-shell-command app-name))
```

Also you can use `(start-process app-name nil app-name)` instead of `(async-shell-command app-name)`, if you don't care for process output according to [Run a program from Emacs and don't wait for output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7298372/596361).

---

See [Minibuffer Completion](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Completion.html#Minibuffer-Completion) for more ideas on completion in Emacs and [Asynchronous Processes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html#Asynchronous-Processes) for calling processes from Emacs, both from GNU manuals.

Answer (score 4):

If you want completion for possible shell commands without needing to maintain a list yourself, and you're using Emacs 23 or newer, you can use `read-shell-command`:

```
(defun app (app-name)
  (interactive (list (read-shell-command "Run application: ")))
  (async-shell-command app-name))
```